# Как внутри блока можно добавить текст c помощью jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть блок. В этот блок вставляется текст или несколько текстов. Например, каждые 5 секунд в блок вставятся разные тексты. Я смог вставить в блог текст, но когда должен добавиться следующий текст, старый удаляется. А мне надо, когда добавляется новая запись, чтобы старая сохранилась. Вот пример кода:

```
$("#information1").text(data);
```

Comment: `$("#information1").text($("#information1").text() + data);` что-то такое.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var data = 'text';

    function updateText (selector, text) {
      var textMethod = $(selector).text;

      textMethod(textMetod(), text);

    };

    updateText('#information1', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#information1").append(data);
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?